# matplotlib make histogram fill plot area

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am doing a plot using matplotlib and i am bothered by the fact that my plot area is bigger then the area occupied by the histogram patches. Here is my problem:

[image: histogram is too narrow or axes too wide ?]

You see, I would like to get rid of the empty space between the "23" patch end the plot's right border.

Here is my code:

```
lines = (' '.join(line.strip().split()) for line in open(filename) if line.strip()) #prepare the date strings
local_dates = ( pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")).astimezone(localtz) for dt in lines )

local_dates = list(local_dates)

#plot by hour of day
bins = range(25)

n,bins,patches = plt.hist([ t.hour for t in local_dates], bins=bins )

xticks_pos = [0.5*patch.get_width() + patch.get_xy()[0] for patch in patches]

plt.xticks(xticks_pos, range(25),  ha='center')


plt.xlabel('Ora')
plt.ylabel('Numar de evenimente')

plt.title(filename, y=1.03)

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(12,8)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, top=0.9, bottom=0.1)
plt.savefig(filename+'.by_hour.png', dpi=100,bbox_inches='tight')
plt.clf()
```

so can i make my patches stretch the entire plot viewport and how ?

Comment: You can use `plt.xlim` to set the limits of the x-axis of a histogram just as for a regular plotted line. In your case, `plt.xlim(0, 23.5)` I guess.

Comment: The above comment is basically right, but I think you might want the limits to be `0,24`